Deploy Google Cloud with GitHub Actions: Function Failed to upload zip file: Could not load the default credentials Error
I want to deploy Google Cloud Function with GitHub Actions.
Did this already with success with gitlab CI/CD and now want to do the same but on GitHub Actions.
I changed parameter names so they should not be the problems:

source to source_dir
my_env_vars to environment_variables etc.

My Code:
name: CI Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:

  deploy-gloud-functions_new:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  
      - name: Setup GCP Service Account
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@main
        with:
          project_id: "cicdtest-421422"
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_ACCOUNT_KEY }}       
        
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: 3.11

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
    
      - name: deploy cloud function
        id: deploy
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@main
        with:
          name: generate_weather_summary
          runtime: python310
          project_id: "cicdtest-421422"
          entry_point: generate_weather_summary
          region: europe-west1
          source_dir: .
          event_trigger_type: topic weather-topic
          memory: 512MB
          environment_variables: "API_KEY=${{ secrets.API_KEY }},SLACK_TOKEN=${{ secrets.SLACK_TOKEN }}"


Error:
Run google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@main
  with:
    name: generate_weather_summary
    runtime: python310
    project_id: cicdtest-421422
    entry_point: generate_weather_summary
    region: europe-west1
    source_dir: .
    event_trigger_type: topic weather-topic
    memory: 512MB
    environment_variables: API_KEY=***,SLACK_TOKEN=***
    universe: googleapis.com
    environment: GEN_2
    all_traffic_on_latest_revision: true
    ingress_settings: ALLOW_ALL
    service_timeout: 60s
    vpc_connector_egress_settings: PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY
    event_trigger_retry: true
  env:
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT: github-actions-setup-gcloud
    CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT_VERSION: 2.1.0
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib
Created zip file from '.' at '/tmp/cfsrc-0ae0bbd4b761ae3f1003cd51.zip'
Error: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to upload zip file: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.


You need to authenticate to Google cloud before you use
google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@main

For example:
- uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
  with:
   credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}' # Replace with the name of your GitHub Actions secret


It helped, now I encountered a new problem but at least I moved forward !
Thank you

Please share the error you are getting now

Error: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to PATCH https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2/projects/cicdtest-421422/locations/europe-west1/functions/generate_weather_summary: (400) ***
"error": ***
"code": 400,
"message": "Function projects/cicdtest-421422/locations/europe-west1/functions/generate_weather_summary already exists in environment GEN_1, can't change it to GEN_2.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"



Try deleting the function first: gcloud functions delete generate_weather_summary --region=europe-west1

Alternatively, change the function name: name: generate_weather_summary_2

I will try deleting it first, I have to also change parameters so its still GEN_1 afterwards

Issue solved, there was a lot of errors actually but finally works
